# Joomla extension layout disable sidebar

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I can't find information how to disable left column in component (administrator submenu) in the code. Actually I would like to override to whole view and left only top menu.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just unpublish every module pointed to the sidebar that you want to hide.

Answer (score -1):

a bit tricky could be, if you hide the DIV with id: j-sidebar-container in the CSS file of Isis template.

jroot/administrator/templates/isis/css/template.css

```
#j-sidebar-container {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I know about that, however thought about there is something like JHTMLSidebar::disable or something

Comment: here you can find all the functions of JHtmlSidebar class: http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtmlSidebar.html

I searched for string "JHtmlSidebar::render" in all files of joomla directory, and all views in administrator has this. So it means you should comment out this expression in all the 35-36 files.

Comment: You can also hack the joomla core (but it is not safe - joomla update can overwrite the change): in file jroot/libraries/cms/html/sidebar.php right before **return $sidebarHtml;** on line 67, place this: **return;** on line 66.

Comment: That's the thing I do not want to hack anything only can change code inside the extension I want to get rid span2 and span10 structure

Comment: Another thing, what you can do is remove the #j-sidebar-container with jQuery.